# Save zoom state per PDF page Adobe Acrobat X Pro

Tags: javascript, pdf, zooming, acrobat, xfa

Need to save zoom level per page in a PDF portfolio.  Tried using the preferences tab and properties tab but this has failed per page.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the zoom level for that particular page in the PageOpen event of that page.